# Blazor - Possible to NavigateTo in code behind?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

Is it possible to navigateto with the navigationmanager in code behind?  I have a global helper class which I need to redirect to a specific page if a global function fails.  Is this possible?  I don't quite get if you are able to create an instance on NavagationManager in code behind.  Or if this is possible, should I use Dependency injection to call naigationmanager?

Comment: Assuming you are calling this global helper class from a component, then you could inject NagivationManager into your component, and pass it into your helper function. There's probably a better way but that's the only way I know how of off the top of my head.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This answer expands on Henk Holterman's great anwser, but includes a full example since services confused me at first and I want people in the future who find this to have a full example.

Here's my `Index.razor` page

```
@page "/"

<TypeScriptTest.Components.MyComponent></TypeScriptTest.Components.MyComponent>
```

Here's my MyComponent.razor:

```
<button @onclick="Test">
    Test
</button>
```

MyComponent.razor.cs:  (This could also be in your @Code block of MyComponent.razor instead but using @inject HelperService at the top instead)

```
 public partial class MyComponent
    {
        [Inject] HelperService HelperService { get; set; }

        public void Test()
        {
            HelperService.ChangePage();
        }
    }
```

`ConfigureServices` inside of `Startup.cs` :

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddServerSideBlazor();
        services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();
        services.AddTransient<HelperService>();
    }
```

And finally, HelperService.cs

```
public class HelperService
{
    private NavigationManager _navigationManager;
    public HelperService(NavigationManager navigationManager)
    {
        _navigationManager = navigationManager;
    }

    public void ChangePage()
    {
        _navigationManager.NavigateTo("/test");
    }
}
```

Using this method, you inject `NavigationManager` into the constructor of your Helper, and then turn your Helper into a service that you can then inject into any component.

Answer (score 4):

> Is it possible to navigateto with the navigationmanager in code behind?
>   I have a global helper class

When you make this Helper class a Scoped or Transient service (ie injectable) then you can easily use constructor injection, problem solved.

```
private NavigationManager _navigationManager;

public MyHelperService(NavigationManager navigationManager)
{
    _navigationManager = navigationManager;
}
```

and then of course, in Startup.ConfigureServices()

```
services.AddTransient<MyHelperService>();
```

The actual navigation should just work.

Comment: Thanks very much all.  Yup that worked, don't know why I didn't do it correctly the first time o_O